# Liquibase VARCHAR2 length in chars

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms, database-migration, liquibase

I would like to define a VARCHAR2 column database independently with size defined in chars.I need to support at least Oracle and PostgreSQL. I use UTF8 encoding, so I have no chance to use byte definition.

I need to use VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) definition in Oracle but CHAR modifier is not valid under other dbms (like PG). Without adding CHAR modifier to the script the generated Oracle definition uses bytes as length: VARCHAR2(255).

What is the proper definition?

Comment: "Proper" definition in Oracle is to use the `CHAR` modifier and in other DBMS's use whatever is valid in those DMBS's. (Making some code that will be valid in all DBMS's will be very hard for you and not going to scale well on any DBMS.) But if you absolutely *have* to, then you might look into the session level parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` ( http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10124.htm#REFRN10124 ). If you set that to `CHAR` in the session that executes the `CREATE TABLE`, then it will be the default for that session .

Comment: We agree, that we have to use CHAR in Oracle. The question is how can I define this in liquibase xml in a way that is the least redundant and database independent.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought by "database independent" you meant you wished for a syntax that worked both in Oracle and Liquibase, and in that case you might have had to "cheat" a bit in Oracle by setting a session parameter so that a `VARCHAR2(255)` would default automatically to `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)`. But if the question really is more about the Liquibase syntax, I will shut up - I know nothing of Liquibase, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a built in way in liquibase to define a datatype as "varchar 255, char type" and have it output VARCHAR(255) on postgresql and VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) on oracle.

Liquibase is designed to be extendable ([liquibase.org/extensions](http://liquibase.org/extensions)) and you should be able to override how the string "VARCHAR(255)" in the changelog is converted to a database-specific type but it will require some java coding.

Alternately, changelog parameters would allow you to dynamically add CHAR to the definition depending on the database. If you add `<property name="varcharUnit" value="CHAR" dbms="oracle"/>` to the top of your changelog, then anywhere in your changelog file you can use `type="VARCHAR(255 ${varcharUnit})"` and it will evaluate to "VARCHAR(255 CHAR)" on oracle and VARCHAR(255) everywhere else. It is more verbose and you need to remember to always add the variable compared to the extension method but it is more straightforward.

Comment: Make sure to have _two_ of those `property` definitions – one for Oracle, and another for all other databases.  List the Oracle one first.  The second one should look just like the first one, but have nothing for the value.

Answer (score 4):

Credit goes to Nathan for the inspiration; I'm just adding some clarity.

```
<property name="char" value="CHAR" dbms="oracle"/>
<property name="char" value=""/>
<changeSet … >
    <createTable tableName="User">
        <column
            name="guid"
            type="VARCHAR(32)"
        />
        <column
            name="name"
            type="VARCHAR(50 ${char})"
        />
        ⋮
```